# TypeError: studentsList.forEach is not a function. Jasmine Unit Testing (Angular 2)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular2-routing, karma-jasmine

How to test the forEach loop in jasmine using karma??
The component code is as follows:-

```
getData(studentsList:any, day:any, game:any){
let strength:any;
let location:string;
   if(studentsList){
    studentsList.forEach( value => {
     strength=value.schedule[day][game].strength;
     location=value.schedule[day][game].location;
});
}
}
```

the data present in studentsList is:-

**(Edit:- the data is updated it looks like this)**

```
    [{
        "activityName": "tournament1",
        "schedule": {
            "first": {
                "Baseball": {
                    "strength": 23,
                    "location": "abc"
                }
            },
            "second": {
                "Cricket": {
                    "strength": 20,
                    "location": "bcd"
                }
            },
            "third": {
                "Football": {
                    "strength": 19,
                    "location": "cde"
                }
            }
        }
    },
{
        "activityName": "tournament2",
        "schedule": {
            "first": {
                "Baseball": {
                    "strength": 23,
                    "location": "abc"
                }
            },
            "second": {
                "Cricket": {
                    "strength": 20,
                    "location": "bcd"
                }
            },
            "third": {
                "Football": {
                    "strength": 19,
                    "location": "cde"
                }
            }
        }
    },{
        "activityName": "tournament3",
        "schedule": {
            "first": {
                "Baseball": {
                    "strength": 23,
                    "location": "abc"
                }
            },
            "second": {
                "Cricket": {
                    "strength": 20,
                    "location": "bcd"
                }
            },
            "third": {
                "Football": {
                    "strength": 19,
                    "location": "cde"
                }
            }
        }
    }]
```

This is the test that I tried:-

```
it('should check getData()', () => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(GameComponent);
        const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
        const data={
    "activityName": "tournament",
    "schedule": {
        "first": {
            "Baseball": {
                "strength": 23,
                "location": "abc"
            }
        },
        "second": {
            "Cricket": {
                "strength": 20,
                "location": "bcd"
            }
        },
        "third": {
            "Football": {
                "strength": 19,
                "location": "cde"
            }
        }
    }
}

app.getData(data, 'first', 'Baseball');
fixture.detectChanges();
expect(app.location).toContain('abc');
expect(app.location).toContain('bcd');
expect(app.location).toContain('cde');
}
```

But I keep on getting this forEach is not a function. Instead of giving static data in the test should I go for some other way?

Comment: `forEach` requires an array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`studentsList` is an object, but `forEach` only exists on arrays. You can use `for (var key in studentsList)` to iterate the keys of the object if that's what you'd like to do.

Comment: Thanks my issue was solved by passing `data=[{
    "activityName": "tournament",
    "schedule": {
        "first": {
            "Baseball": {
                "strength": 23,
                "location": "abc"
            }
        },
        "second": {
            "Cricket": {
                "strength": 20,
                "location": "bcd"
            }
        },
        "third": {
            "Football": {
                "strength": 19,
                "location": "cde"
            }
        }
    }
}]` as array